# MS Access VBA ADODB Recordset.Open table OK but SQL fails

Tags: ms-access, vba

[image]

I have an MS Access 2007 table:

Columns are DB, Module, CommentID, and Comment

I have an SQL query that returns the correct record in MS Access Query Design.

I have confirmed in the Immediate window that the sql is identical in Ms Access Query Design and the VBA module "Module1".

I call the function as below:

```
?LookupComment(currentproject.Name,Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule,"1")
```

Subsequently strSQL in the function is confirmed in the immediate window as

```
Select * from tblComments where DB='db1.accdb' AND Module='Module1' AND CommentID='1'
```

If I replace "strSQ" with the "tblComments" the functions returns fine.

But I am getting an error at the rst.open with strSQL

*Method 'Open' of Object '_Recordset' failed*

```
Public Function LookupComment(theDB, theModule, theCommentID As String) As String

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

strSQL = "Select * from tblComments where DB='" & theDB & "' AND " _
    & "Module='" & theModule & "' AND CommentID='" & theCommentID & "'"
rst.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

' rst.Open "tblComments", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

If rst.EOF = False Or rst.BOF = False Then
    rst.MoveFirst
    LookupComment = rst!Comment
End If

Set rst = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing


End Function
```

Thoughts?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test your function with this change:

```
strSQL = "Select * from tblComments where DB='" & theDB & "' AND " _
    & "[Module]='" & theModule & "' AND CommentID='" & theCommentID & "'"
```

I surrounded `Module` with square brackets because it is a Jet reserved word.  See [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#M).

A SELECT statement with that un-bracketed name causes the ADO recordset `.Open` method to fail.  As you reported, it succeeds when the same SELECT statement is used for a query opened in the query designer.  And Igor's DAO recordset suggestion also worked for me whether or not I enclosed `Module` with brackets; I don't understand why it failed for you.

It's difficult to predict exactly when using reserved words as db object names will bite you in the butt.  It's safer to avoid using them entirely.  If you can't avoid them, enclose those names in square brackets in your queries to reduce the likelihood of confusing the db engine.

You can download Allen Browne's free [Database Issue Checker Utility](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueChecker.html) and use it to examine your database for reserved words.  It will also warn you about other potential problem issues with your database.

Comment: Actually I thought about brackets, but tested and it worked just fine without them.

Comment: @IgorTurman If you mean with your DAO recordset approach, yes I agree it works without the brackets.  But I couldn't get the ADO recordset approach to work without brackets.  I don't understand why it's a problem for ADO and not for DAO.  OTOH, I don't care much  because I avoid reserved words for table and field names.  :-)

Comment: Reserved names was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use DAO Recordset instead:

```
Public Function LookupComment(theDB, theModule, theCommentID As String) As String

Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "Select * from tblComments where DB='" & theDB & "' AND " _
    & "Module='" & theModule & "' AND CommentID='" & theCommentID & "'"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If rst.EOF = False Or rst.BOF = False Then
    rst.MoveFirst
    LookupComment = rst!Comment
End If

Set rst = Nothing

End Function
```

On the side note, are you sure you need CommentID as string/text type?

Comment: Thanks. Copied and pasted your code still falls over on the SQL.

Comment: Error message is expects 2 parameters. "tblComments works fine

Comment: @user824232: Before I posted, I tested the code. It does work! If you get "expected 2 parameters" error it means TWO out of three your column names are invalid. Make sure DB, Module and CommentID are valid column names.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a semi-colon at the end of your query.